# How to write SQL Query to get value from excel file based on sheet tab position

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I want to get data by using SQL query in SSIS.
Am using Excel source in data flow task in which I have selected Data access mode as SQL COMMAND.

now I want to query the excel sheet based on sheet position. My sheet1 name is CA.
if I write query like

```
Select state, name, zip from [CA$]
```

it is working correctly.

But I want to query it based on sheet tab position name, because am having many excel file which has different sheet name(like CA,AZ etc.,).I want to query only 1st sheet name, other sheets I don't care. I googled it but not finding proper solution.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Is it possible to write like this?
Select state,name,zip from [sheet1$]
But my sheet name here is CA.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about SSIS but you might try assigning the first sheet's name to a variable and using the variable name in your query statement, something like this perhaps

```
wsNme = Sheets(1).Name
"SELECT ..... FROM [" & wsNme & "$]"
```

Comment: yeah if I could not able to find the solution then I have use variable and use it at runtime.

Comment: my sheet name is always changing, so i need to take based on sheet position.

Comment: @Govind, this is exactly what the suggestion does - based on sheet position 1.  If you wanted to use sheet position 2 then substitute for Sheets(2) and so on.  You don't need to know the name, the code automatically puts it into the variable wsName (which should be declared as type String) for use in your Select query.

Comment: We can achieve this in c# code, in ssis the same thing should be achieved. I can pass this as variable name. But in c# i am not allowed to use interop dll, bcoz in prod office products will not be installed.

Comment: I have achieved the same in script task by using oledb without using interop.

Comment: My question is can't we query excel file based on sheet position in ssis itself without passing variable's